# Nested Object List DataBinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am working on a project that is an addin to Autodesk's Revit program, and I am having issues getting all of the Data-Bindings to work in the ViewModel hell I have created. I have multiple element type classes that have a few properties and a list of parameters. The parameters are from a parameter class that has a name, a value, and a  boolean for if the parameter is IsReadOnly. In my WPF form I have a ListBox for selecting an element, and a DataGrid to display the parameters for editing. In the MainViewModel I execute an ICommand to create a Zone from an element in Revit, and then create a ZoneViewModel for the zone and add it to an observable collection called Zones.

I have created a ViewModel for each element type, and a generic ParameterViewModel to be used for the parameters. I have included an example for the Zone element below.

ZoneViewModel:

```
    public class ZoneViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Element _element;
        private EngineZone _zone;

        public EngineZone EZone;
        private ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> Parameters
        {
            get => _parameters;
            set => _parameters = value;
        }

        private string _elementId;
        public string ElementId
        {
            get => _elementId = EZone.ElementId;
            set => _elementId = EZone.ElementId;
        }

        private EngineParameter _name;
        public EngineParameter Name
        {
            get => _name = EZone.Name;
            set
            {
                _name = EZone.Name;
                RaiseProperty(nameof(Name));
            }
        }

        public EngineParameter Area
        {
            get => EZone.Area;
        }

        #region Default Constructor

        public ZoneViewModel(EngineZone zone)
        {
            EZone = zone;
            ElementId = zone.ElementId;

            Parameters.Add(new ParameterViewModel(EZone.Name, false));
            Parameters.Add(new ParameterViewModel(EZone.Area, true));
        }

        #endregion
```

ParameterViewModel:

```
    public class ParameterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private EngineParameter _parameter;
    private bool _isReadOnly;
    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get => _isReadOnly;
        set => _isReadOnly = value;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _parameter.Name;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get => _parameter.Value;
        set
        {
            if (!_isReadOnly)
            {
                _parameter.Value = value;
                RaiseProperty(nameof(Value));
            }
        }
    }

    public ParameterViewModel(EngineParameter parameter, bool isReadOnly)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

The issue I am running into is that when changing the value of the parameter in my DataGrid does not update the property in the ZoneViewModel.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nza0Z.png) - Everything works fine when adding the zones to the collection initially.

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4o9c.png) - After the name is changed, the zone element reflects the change but the value in the ListBox does not update.

The XAML code for the data grid and box are below.

```
            <!--Column 1-->

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="Zones" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="16" />
            <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Zones}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Zone "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name.Value}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ElementId}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

            <!--Column 2-->

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="Info" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="16" />

            <DataGrid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" HeadersVisibility="None"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Parameters}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                                         Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="False"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Name}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Value}" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

My question is why is the ListBox value not updating? Is it somehow referencing a different parameter/property? I have tried stepping through the debug process, but I am new to programming and am having a hard time tracking down what is going wrong.

Comment: Check the Output window. Error messages will tell you that you have binding errors.

Comment: You can also debug your bindings: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/

Comment: `Name` and `Area` need to be `ParameterViewModel`, not `EngineParameter`. Then put those actual instances in your Parameters collection, so that the ListBox and the DataGrid are looking at the same object. Either that, or make `ParameterViewModel` for "Name" tell `ZoneViewModel` to raise `PropertyChanged("Name")`. As you have it, you're not raising any change notifications that the ListBox has any way of handling. `EZone.Name` changes, but it doesn't tell anybody to tell the ListBox that it changed.

Comment: Ed, you are a genius! I couldn't work out where the disconnect was but I knew it was in the `ZoneViewModel` and the nesting of the `ParameterViewModel` list. Thanks for the help!